# rake: command not found in Jenkins installed on AWS EC2

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to build a code using jenkins, jenkins is giving any error that rake: command not found and my build goes into the failure state.
Tried to add the location of rake into the path and .bashrc file but same error is there.

Answer (score 0):

Install rake.

```
yum install rake
```